# html() & text() ignoring \n and <br />

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand why this is happening, basically i got some description of some app from Google play store, in the form of JSON, now i am using jQuery to add the description into some div, but instead of actually printing as it is, it gives a block of paragraph and ignores \n or `<br />` tag.

```
var description = json.description;
alert(description);
```

When I alert this description, as shown above, there is proper paragraph format with next line[\n] included just like I want it, but when I add it to the required div with either `html()` or `text()`, it ignores the next line `\n`

`$('#appName').html(description)`;

I tried to replace the next line with the 
 tags, but still the result was same, I don't know why

```
var test = description.replace(/\s\n+/g, '<br />');
$('#appName').html(description)
```

Comment: Newline (\n) will not make much difference in html formatting. If you change your `<div>` tag to `<pre>` tag and add text which has `\n` they will be displayed as they should. `<br />` tags should be shown tho when passed to `$.html()`. Can you make a fiddle example?

Comment: You are using description instead of test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var test = description.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
$('#appName').html(test );
```

Your regex would not work if there is no white space before newline character.  also you dont need to put + as /g will replace all new line characters.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is searching for a css solution. It's not neccecarry to do this with a regex as you can simply add the `white-space` property. If you set it to `pre-wrap`, `\n` results in  a new line.

```
.show-white-space {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

just add the class to your `<p>` or `<div>` tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = description.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
$('#appName').html(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression for .replace().:

```
$('#appName').html(description.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
```

If those linebreaks were made by windows-encoding, you will also have to replace the carriage return.

```
$('#appName').html(description.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br />"));
```